# What's best options for video streaming or max data transfer using SuperWebSocket

Tags: html, ssl, websocket, video-streaming

Minimum To Achieve:- Send nearly or more than 1 mb/second to other websocket clients.

Questions:--

1. Is it possible video streaming with SuperWebSocket?
2. What options/features of SuperWebSocket can be used like Asynch
   mode/JsonCommands/CustomSession/etc to achieve fastest data
   transfer?
3. How to sequence a big data sent in chunks but if received without any order at client or server side? Is there anything built in to sequence these chunks or I have to manually send sequence nos in message itself?
4. What I have tried:-- 
   Multiple secure sessions with same port and different paths in javascript code

   - ws = new WebSocket(wss://localhost:8089/1/1)
   - ws = new WebSocket(wss://localhost:8089/2/2)
   - ws = new WebSocket(wss://localhost:8089/3/3)

with above sessions I send large data in chunks but it's not receiving in expected order at server/client side and also after successfully sending large chunk (size=55000kb) that session closes automatically!

I am looking into sample projects of SuperWebSocket but not sure where to go!  I am open to try any option inside SuperWebsocket.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1) I am not sure it does, but if it provides an API to send `Byte[]`, it may be enough.

2) No idea about this one, [the documentation](http://supersocket.codeplex.com/documentation) may explain it.

3) What do you mean without order? WebSockets is TCP based, so data segments sent in the same connection will arrive in the same order they were sent.

4) Why would you open different connections to the same site? There is also probably limitations about the connections that you can open to the same host. One should be OK, open several is not going to increment your bandwidth, only will increment your problems.

I develop a WebSocket server component that [handles messages as `Stream` derived objects](https://github.com/vtortola/WebSocketListener#receiving-messages) and has an [acceptable performance](https://github.com/vtortola/WebSocketListener/wiki/WebSocketListener-performance-tests) so far, you may like to give it a try.

Comment: Hi vtortola,

1] ok
2] No problem.
3] True at server side it's serial but client connections do not accept in sequence! Means 3rd client receive before 1st.
4] I think you are right if data is going to received in sequence it is sent at server side. So no need of multiple connections. But in which scene such multiple connections can be used?
   I will try your websocket server component and get back to you.

Comment: Honestly I do not see any use for WS connections in parallel. Cheers.